# How to show sign-in sign-out to Facebook users?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to enable users to login. It works perfectly but the problem is that it shows the name of website rather than signin - sign out so user is not able to sign out. how should I change it to enable users to sign out ? based on blew comment I added autologoutlink="true"  and now singout is visible but when user is signed in it write a sentence as following jack is logged in myproject (jack is username and myproject is name of my project)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });


  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));


  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the actual html for the button

Comment: @raam86 question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autologoutlink="true"`

Add this parameter to your `fb:login-button`:

`<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" autologoutlink="true" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: great, but when I logout it shows the small window of Facebook to logout how can I keep it in my website page?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: is your problem solved? if not please explain it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it shows the sign in and sing out buttons but when user is signs in it write a sentence as following jack is logged in myproject (jack is username and myproject is name of my project)

Comment: I see I will give it a try where do you get this info from ? I could not find them on facebook.

Comment: We have to dig deep in the Facebook docs to find all this. Try it and tell if it works or not.

Comment: did you replaced this `show-faces="true"` with this `show-faces="false"`? Can you upload a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Great it works now, would you please have a look at this question as well many thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618398/facebook-does-not-show-thumbnail-when-a-photo-is-shared

Comment: yeah, i would help out on that question but before that if this problem is solved then please close this question by accepting the answer...

Comment: Oooo I am sorry I forgot.